# Cypress not receiving Firebase Messaging Token

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, cypress

I'm using **Cypress** to test my project code, it work all fine until when I tried to test my push notification with **Firebase Messaging** function. It worked all fine in my project but not in **Cypress**. In my project I'm able to fetch the token and receive test notification, but in **Cypress** I am not getting any response from **Firebase**.

So what I've tried is **Cypress-Firebase** method, but not working as well as other research.

Any idea what's the problem and what I should try?